# How Does Rust's println! macro perform dereferencing?

Tags: macros, rust, dereference

The `println!` macro handles both values and references without requiring explicit dereferencing.

First, create a vector

```
let v = vec![0, 2, 3, -4];
```

1. Printing references from `vec.iter`

   ```
   for x in v.iter() {
       println!("x: {}", x);
   }
   ```
2. Printing dereferenced elements from `vec.iter`

   ```
   for x in v.iter() {
       println!("x: {}", *x);
   }
   ```
3. Printing values from `vec`

   ```
   for x in v {
       println!("x: {}", x);
   }
   ```

How is the internal dereferencing in Case 1 done?

I know internally `println!` makes another macro call but the last macro in the chain `format_args!` is implemented at the compiler level and I have no view into it.

```
macro_rules! println {
    ($fmt:expr) => (print!(concat!($fmt, "\n")));
    ($fmt:expr, $($arg:tt)*) => (print!(concat!($fmt, "\n"), $($arg)*));
}

macro_rules! print {
    ($($arg:tt)*) => ($crate::io::_print(format_args!($($arg)*)));
}

macro_rules! format_args {
    ($fmt:expr, $($args:tt)*) => ({ /* compiler built-in */ })
}
```

[Source code Reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.6.0/src/std/macros.rs.html#118-121)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The important thing here is that using `{}` in the format string invokes the `Display` trait on the value passed.

As expected, [the i32 type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i32.html) implements `Display`, which is what allows your case #2 and case #3 to work. Because they are getting a standard `i32` value, not a reference, it all works.

For your case #1, `x` would be an `&i32`, which seems to be the core of your question. The answer there is in [the `Display` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Display.html#impl-Display-for-%26T). Display contains the following:

```
impl<'a, T> Display for &'a T 
where
    T: Display + ?Sized
```

which says "for the reference type of `T`, implement `Display` if `T` implements `Display`". This means that because `i32` implements `Display`, the reference type also implements it automatically.

There is no special type handling being done by the compiler here. The compiler-implemented code passes on that responsibility to the `Display` trait's implementation.

Comment: >> As expected, the i32 type implements Display, which is what allows your  case #1 and case #2 to work. Because they are getting a standard i32  value, not a reference, it all works.<< Do you mean case #2 and #3? Case #1 is a reference

Comment: Sorry 100% typoed the case numbers.

Comment: I am still lost. Ok, there's automatic blanket implementation of Display trait for &T, right? But where does it says that println! should dereference references and print out values? I still don't see the logic while rereading this answer :(